# How to make Angular-CLI compile SCSS to CSS in assets folder

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli

I have an Angular 4 project, created with angular-cli 1.0.x.
At this time, angular-cli is upgraded to 1.1.1 in my project.

I have an assets folder and when I put a css file in it, it can be used.
But when I rename the css file to scss, it is not compiled by angular-cli.

What do I need to do to get the scss file to be compiled to css?

This is my project's package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my project",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/upgrade": "4.1.3",
    "@axinpm/ang-core": "^0.2.3",
    "chart.js": "2.5.0",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "moment": "2.18.1",
    "ng2-charts": "1.5.0",
    "ng2draggable": "^1.3.2",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "1.6.6",
    "rxjs": "5.4.0",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "zone.js": "0.8.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.47",
    "@types/node": "7.0.22",
    "codelyzer": "3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.1.0",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.2.1",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "3.0.4",
    "tslint": "5.3.2",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  }
}
```

This is my project's .angular-cli.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-alpha.6",
    "name": "my project"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": ["assets"],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "scss/style.scss"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js",
        "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "prefixInterfaces": false
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

That happening because `assets` folder is used for a static content as per `.angular-cli.json` config:

```
"assets": ["assets"]
```

So by having that setting, all `assets` folder content gets always copied like it is. You have to place your `.scss` outside `assets` folder to avoid it outputted by cli build tool chain. You also might consider to crate a separate folder for your custom `scss` files.

> However it should not brake your app anyway if you have your `scss` referenced correctly.

If say, you have `theme.scss` file in your `assets` folder you can reference that in your global `styles.scss` like `@import '/assets/theme';` it will just work anyway as cli will produce a build. Then after the build has produced all your styles ended up injected in to `styles.bundle.js`. At this point there is no use of your `assets/theme.scss` file in runtime but in case running the command `ng build` it will remain in `assets` folder anyway. So you have better take it out from `assets` folder to keep it clean from unnecessary files.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new folder named "styles" parallel to "assets" folder and place your `.scss` file there and refer the `.scss` file in the "styles" node of `.angular-cli.json` file:

```
"styles": [
  "./styles/site.scss"
]
```

If still not working then add this to the "defaults" node of `.angular-cli.json`:

```
"defaults": {
  "styleExt": "css",
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To change the existing style of your project you need to run this command.

```
ng set defaults.styleExt scss
```

It will change the extension and you will be able to access SCSS styles.

Keep your `SCSS` files under `assets` folder as @Kuncevic mentioned that `assets` folder contains static contents.

Comment: I tried this command, saw that the option was added to .angular-cli.json, renamed my .css to .scss and restarted ng serve. But the styles are not used anymore...

Comment: Yes indeed. O, do I need to change my stylesheet links to .scss too? Or are the scss files still transpiled to css somewhere along the road?

Comment: It is difficult to say how you are using it. But my best guess is change stylesheet links to .scss and check what happens.